# Small Icon Of Notifications Are Not Drawn In Gray On Oreo?

Tags: android, android-notifications

For Android 21+ notification small icons must be alpha-only. Otherwise android will draw them in gray color.

I put here notification screenshots of two devices, one is Oreo and other is Pie, so both are 21+

Android Pie (Xiaomi Mi 6), this is okay it draws the icon in gray
[image]

Android Oreo (Samsung Galaxy A - 2016), the small icon is not drawn in gray. **Is not it weird ?**
[image]

Code of notification,

```
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat
            .Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_bos_new)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSubText(subtitle)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yellow), 1000, 1000)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .build();
```

Why this doesn't behave same on all 21+ devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Because at some point Google realized that notification bar backgrounds can be any color, so that meant they had to restrict those icons to using only the alpha channel. This allows the system to automatically recolor the icons to achieve maximum contrast.

Comment: I can understand the reason of behind this, for 21+ devices.  But wondering the second screenshot, why this small icon drawn properly ? This device is also 21+